# Capture words and rewrite

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, url-rewriting, pos-tagger

Made a word classifier with nlpnet (http://nilc.icmc.usp.br/nlpnet/index.html). the goal is to extract only words individually with given tagger.

**response code**

```
import nlpnet
import codecs
import itertools

TAGGER = nlpnet.POSTagger('pos-pt', language='pt')


def TAGGER_txt(text):
    return (list(TAGGER.tag(text)))

with codecs.open('document.txt', encoding='utf8') as original_file:
     with codecs.open('document_teste.txt', 'w') as output_file:
          for line in original_file.readlines():
          print (line)
          words = TAGGER_txt(line)
          all_words = list(itertools.chain(*words))
          nouns = [word[0] for word in all_words if word[1]=='V']
          print (nouns)
```

**Result**

```
O gato esta querendo comer o ratão 
['gato', 'ratão']
```

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show a Example Sentence with more than 5 Verb and also the output of `print(TAGGER.tag(Sentence)[0].arg_structures)` of that Sentence.

Comment: Does a single line of the input file contain some integer multiple number of Portuguese sentences? By this I mean, no extra words such as from the end of the previous sentence or from the beginning of the next sentence?

Comment: @stovfl I edited the question, see if it's clearer.

Comment: @BillBell And a text document with several lines of text, of various sizes and with different words.

Comment: (1) Let me put my question another way: If I read one line of the input text file will that contain exactly one sentence? (2) Instead of giving us images would you please insert text in your question so that we can copy it conveniently?

Comment: @stovfl I can not apply *.arg_structures* In the code. I'm totally clueless where to put this function from my code

Comment: (1) Yes, all lines are composed of sentences.
(2) The file in which I want to process and a dataset of opinions in which the purpose of me to extract these words, is to acquire characteristics of these texts. @BillBell

Comment: the function *arg_structures* give error : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'arg_structures'   @stovfl

Comment: My bad, I overlooked you are using `POSTagger` instead of `nlpnet.SRLTagger()`. If you don't want to switch we have to continue with the Output of `POSTagger`. Please provide the Output showing in the image as text so I can use it in my Answer Example.

Comment: Edited the output. @stovfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be the essence of what you need. **Please see edited version.**

As you say in your question, the result of tagging `Sentence` would be something like `tagged`. If you wanted just the nouns from `Sentence` you could recover them using the expression after `nouns =`.

```
Sentence = " O gato esta querendo comer o rato "  
tagged = [('O', 'ADJ'), ('gato', 'N'), ('esta', 'V'), ('querendo', 'V'), ('comer', 'V'), ('o', 'ADJ'), ('rato', 'N')]

nouns = [t[0] for t in tagged if t[1]=='N']

print (nouns)
```

Output:

```
['gato', 'rato']
```

**Edit:** It's not clear to me what you want. Here's another possibility.

- I haven't installed nlpnet because that would be quite a bit of work and I wouldn't use it myself.
- I simulate TAGGER.txt with TAGGER_txt.
- I've changed the encoding to Latin-1. It's used in the header and in `codecs.open`.

.

```
# -*- coding: Latin-1 -*-
import codecs
import itertools

def TAGGER_txt(text): ## simulate TAGGER.txt
    return [[(u'O', u'ART'), (u'gato', u'N'), (u'esta', u'PROADJ'), (u'querendo', u'V'), (u'comer', u'V'), (u'o', u'ART'), (u'ratão', u'N')]]

with codecs.open('document.txt', encoding='Latin-1') as original_file:
    with codecs.open('document_test.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in original_file.readlines():
            print (line)
            words = TAGGER_txt(line)
            all_words = list(itertools.chain(*words))
            nouns = [word[0] for word in all_words if word[1]=='N']
            print (nouns)
```

Output:

```
 O gato esta querendo comer o ratão 
['gato', 'ratão']
```

Comment: I understand your logic. However in the *tagged* parameter I am not able to apply to my codic efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

> **Question**: ... dump to a file the sentences that contain more than N occurrences of a particular POS

---

> **Note**: Assuming `'document.txt'` contains **one** Sentence per Line!

```
def is_worth_saving(tags, pos, pos_count):
    """
    :param tags:        nlpnet tags from ONE Sentence
    :param pos:         The POS to filter
    :param pos_count:   Number of 'param pos'
    :return:
        True if 'tags' contain more than 'pos_count' occurrences of 'pos'
        False otherwise
    """  
    pos_found = 0
    # Iterate tags
    for word, _pos in tags:
        if _pos == pos:
            pos_found += 1

    return pos_found >= pos_count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('document.txt') as in_fh, open('document_test.txt', 'w') as out_fh:
        for sentence in in_fh:
            print('Sentence:{}'.format(sentence[:-1]))
            tags = TAGGER.tag(sentence)

            # As your Example Sentence has only **2** Verbs,
            # pass 'pos_count=2'
            if is_worth_saving(tags[0], 'V', 2):
                out_fh.write(sentence)
                print (tags[0])
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> Sentence:O gato esta querendo comer o ratão
> [(u'O', u'ART'), (u'gato', u'N'), (u'esta', u'PROADJ'), (u'querendo', u'V'), (u'comer', u'V'), (u'o', u'ART'), (u'rat', u'N')]
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 and 2.7.9***

Comment: I need to capture only words with class n.

Comment: @Jeferson: [Edit] your Question and show your expected Output or  take the Answer from #Bill Bell.

Comment: Sorry, I did not want to explain my question.